# ValueListenableBuilder not rebuilding a CheckboxListTile Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to run a method that updates the value of a `CheckboxListTile` as I pass the new values at the end at `Globals.data.updateFilterSelection(newFilters);` the method runs fine and it do updates (tested it with prints), but the `ValueListenableBuilder` is not rebuilding the `CheckboxListTile` when I change its value.

I have three `CheckboxListTile` with the same code but different logic all of them listening to `Globals.data.filterSelection,`

What I am missing?

Hi here is the code:

```
       ValueListenableBuilder<Map>(
            valueListenable: Globals.data.filterSelection,
            builder: (context, value, _) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                activeColor: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                value: value['all_neighbors'],
                secondary: Icon(
                  Icons.people,
                  color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  'All Neighbors',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                ),
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  if (newValue) {
                    newFilters
                      ..update('inactive', (value) => false)
                      ..update('active', (value) => false)
                      ..update('all_neighbors', (value) => true);
                  } else {
                    newFilters
                      ..update('inactive', (value) => true)
                      ..update('all_neighbors', (value) => false);
                  }
                  Globals.data.updateFilterSelection(newFilters);
                },
              );
            }),
```

Here is also my `ValueNotifier` and the method called:

```
  ValueNotifier<Map> filterSelection = ValueNotifier<Map>({
    'inactive': true,
    'active': false,
    'all_neighbors': false,
  });

  /// Changes the filter selection
  void updateFilterSelection(Map newFilter) {
    filterSelection.value = newFilter;
    print(filterSelection.value);
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I found out that the `ValueListenableBuilder` does not rebuild on `<Map>` types it needs to be a single value that can be compared with the `==` operator, as described.

> When value is replaced with something that is not equal to the old value as evaluated by the equality operator ==, this class notifies its listeners.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it certainly helped me. If anyone is using stateful widget in ValueListenableBuilder, do add a key for the widget so that it can update.